# How to share github pages to facebook? I tried sharing my blog but it didn't work

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have just created a [github page](https://crazz-zaac.github.io/my-blog/car-detection-with-yolo/) and written a blog. I tried sharing with **Disqus**'s share option to Facebook but it's not loading preview and also says following.

[image: Site not found]

Even though I copy the link and directly paste it, it's not working. But if I do the same (copy the link and paste) in **LinkedIn** it preview is generated finely. What could be the problem? I'm using *Flexible-Jekyll* theme. You can find the link to [flexible-jekyll theme](https://jekyllthemes.io/theme/flexible-jekyll) here and here's a link to my [github repo](https://github.com/Crazz-Zaac/my-blog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by this line of code from the [source code of 'Car detection with YOLO'](https://github.com/Crazz-Zaac/crazz-zaac.github.io/blob/master/_site/car-detection-with-yolo/index.html#L27):

```
<meta content="https://crazz-zaac.github.io/crazz-zaac.github.iohttps://crazz-zaac.github.io/car-detection-with-yolo/" property="og:url">
```

The URL is incorrect in the the `og:url` property, but it is working fine in Twitter because you have provided different `og:url` property for Twitter.
Change it to the correct URL and I hope it will work,

```
<meta content="https://crazz-zaac.github.io/car-detection-with-yolo/" property="og:url">
```